# How do you see the full "called from" chain of function calls after an error?

Tags: gap-system

Upon getting an error in the GAP command line interpreter, the chain of function calls that led to the error get's truncated, so I can see the *start* of the chain, which is the function I'd need to fix.

```gap
gap> MyAwesomeFunction(x,y);
Error, resulting list would be too large (length infinity) called from
ConstantTimeAccessList( enum ) at /path/to/gap/lib/coll.gi:506 called from
AsList( l ) at /path/to/gap/lib/list.gi:612 called from
AsPlist( l ) at /path/to/gap/lib/list.gi:673 called from
EnumeratorSorted( Enumerator( D ) ) at /path/to/gap/lib/domain.gi:231 called from
EnumeratorSorted( C ) at /path/to/gap/lib/coll.gi:862 called from
...  at line 4 of *stdin*
you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
you can 'return;' to continue
brk>
```

How do I tell GAP to show me the full chain of functions here? What's behind that `...`?

Comment: Look at this chapter: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap7.htm, the function you need is called `Where`. For example, enter `Where(1000);` in the break loop to show last 1000 commands on the execution stack during whose execution the error occurred.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you! You know you have a habit of leaving answers as comments. ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) That habit may change if there will be a larger GAP community here - but so far https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gap is much larger, and I am not very keen to disperse GAP questions across all other sites. But indeed pure programming questions like this one will likely be considered off-topic there. Also, a comment is much faster, and it seems from the question that you may appreciate a quick help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Alexander Konovalov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759824/how-do-you-see-the-full-called-from-chain-of-function-calls-after-an-error?noredirect=1#comment111005123_62759824), the [Where](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X7A7FFA2B7C1EF5A3) function is the key here. Entering `Where(42)` in the break look will show up to 42 functions in this "called from" chain.